# Is there a way to remove a folder that are add but not commit in cvs

Tags: cvs

I have use `cvs add` on a folder but have not use `cvs commit` on it yet. Now i want to remove it. Is that possible? Or it would be the same as from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204991/remove-empty-directory-from-cvs) where any removal is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your suspicions are right. CVS does not offer a way to remove directories. When it comes to directories, the `add` is the important thing. The fact that you haven't done a `commit` doesn't matter as the `add` will create the directory in the repository.

Refer to the answer you linked to for ways to remove or ignore the empty directory.

(As an aside, I hope this incident is gentle encouragement to start using more modern/better version control systems such as git)